# Multiple instances of a Quarts job to emulate timer functionality

Tags: grails, timer, quartz-scheduler

I have a Grails application and need to set a timer, something that will initiate a broadcast via WebSocket at a given time, with the following stipulations:

- A timer can be postponed or cancelled
- There might be several different timers running at the same time (but with different "contexts")
- Clustered mode should be supported, i.e. a timer fires only once regardless of the number of instances of my app in a cluster.

The solution I have come up with is:

- Use Quartz to create an ordinary job without any given date for when it should be fired
- The moment I want to set a timer, I create a new instance of the job with a **cronExpression** to fire it at a given time, and then save it persistently
- Should I need to postpone the timer, I fetch it from the DB and rewrite the **cronExpression** to a new value instead.

My concerns are:

1. Is there any other way I can "set a timer" in Grails, possibly without using the concept of Quartz jobs?
2. It is [possible to have multiple instances of a Quartz job](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/06/14/running-multiple-instances-of-a-quartz-job-dynamically/), but is it the right way to use Quartz, or should it be avoided? Maybe I should use [custom triggers](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/triggers.html) instead?
3. If I go the way I explained before, is it going to work in a clustered mode (multiple instances)?

Comment: Are 4 quarts jobs considered a gallon job?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Sorry, don't get it. What do you mean? Potentially there might might be tens of jobs ("timers") running simultaneously.